# How to know which intent is selected in Intent.ACTION_SEND in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bluetooth

want to use Android Intent.ACTION_SEND for quickly sharing something. i wrote some code  and i can show custom shearing dialog 
but i want to check intent is selected in Intent.ACTION_SEND,for example if i  send some files from Gmail  i want to show Toast message( message sent from Gmail and etc)
this is a my source

```
 PackageManager pm = mActivity.getPackageManager();


    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    Uri photoUri = Uri.parse(path);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  "Downloading your app");

    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoUri);


    List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
    for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList)
    {
        Log.e("Application pachage",app.activityInfo.name +"package");
        if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("Bluetooth"))
        {
            Log.e("Application pachage","mee" +"package");
            Toast.makeText(mActivity,"Message sent from Bluetooth",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
            final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
            shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            shareIntent.setComponent(name);
            mActivity.startActivity(shareIntent);
            break;
        }
    }
```

So, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Only on Android 5.1+, if you use [the three-parameter flavor of `createChooser()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.IntentSender%29), where you can supply an `IntentSender` that is notified about the choice.

Otherwise, you would need to roll your own chooser-style UI, then use the user's choice to craft an explicit `Intent` to route the user to the requested activity.